# How to implement SSO using SAML 2.0 protocol for an Android application?

Tags: android, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

I want to implement SSO login using `SAML 2.0 protocol`, with Azure Active Directory for my android application, however, I did not come across any documentation/resources for `Android`. I came across Microsoft's MSAL SSO authentication, but it is based on the `OpenID Connect (OICD) protocol`, hence I cannot use that.

Here is a link I came across to implement SSO using SAML with Azure AD, but it doesn't mention about Android implementation anywhere - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-on-saml-protocol

Has anyone implemented SSO login using SAML 2.0 protocol only, and if so, how did you achieve it, or if anyone knows of any resources/documentation for Android, it will be very helpful.

I read about `WebView` not being the ideal approach for SSO, hence not using that as well.